# C++ The relationship between the address and value of a array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

```
int arr[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    cout <<"the address of the first element: "<< (int)arr << endl;
    cout <<"(the address of the first element)+1: " <<(int)arr + 1 << endl;
    cout << "(the value of the address of the first element)+1: " << *(arr + 1) << endl;
    cout <<"the value of the address of the second element: " <<arr[1] << endl;
    cout <<"the address of the second element: "<< (int)&arr[1] << endl;
```

Why does "(the address of the first element)+1" belong to the space of the first element, but it is printed out as the value of the second space (int 2)?

Comment: because `(int)arr+1` and `arr+1` are different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Adding 1 to an `int` and adding 1 to an `int*` are not the same operations. Adding to a pointer advances the pointer in multiples of the size of the type.

Try printing `(int)(arr + 1)`, and you'll see that it's not the same as `(int)arr + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

At first I should say that casting address to `int` is an invalid operation. Results for 64 bit OS is always incorrect. You may use `uintptr_t` if your compiler supports.

Second thing you should know that `(int)arr + 1` means cast `arr` to `int` then add one. This is an arithmetic operation on `int` that adds one. But `arr + 1` means add 1 to **pointer**. This operation is pointer arithmetic which adds `sizeof(int)` to pointer address because pointer is `int*`(normally 4).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that it adds `sizeof(int)`; that is probably 4, but it's not guaranteed to be on all systems.